# User Logging history in MS CRM 2011?

Tags: history, trace, crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I want to know how to get the user loggin history for MS Dynamics CRM 2011? e.g. How manu user access to the CRM and what are their details and datetime be greate.

I have tried looked in IIS log, CRM Trace log but cann't manage to get the list of users who access CRM server in Last week or in certain dates.

It would be appreciated if you help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [the latest rollup pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27820) and then it is a native feature.

A good blog on this can be found [here](http://www.zero2ten.com/Blog/tabid/63/EntryId/74/Auditing-User-Access-in-Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)

Edit:
Based on your comment below, installing rollup pack 5 is not an option. The reasons for that are not given and is something you should look at separately.

You would need to enabled auditing on your organisation and then write a report/custom application that searches auditing logs and filters on the action types below:

```
AuditAction.UserAccessAuditStarted
AuditAction.UserAccessAuditStopped
AuditAction.UserAccessviaWebServices
AuditAction.UserAccessviaWeb
```

Example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547448.aspx).
It is a bit long winded, but well commented.

Comment: Thank you for answer it seems correct, but unfortunitly we are running RU3 and can't upgrade to 5 because of some reason, so please advise me if there is any other way we can get this information.